# sudo: docker-machine: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

who has ever tried following this tutorial about **Docker Swarm**?

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/

There is a section called : **Create a cluster**. What I wanted to do was to create a couple of VMs using docker-machine. Since I use ubuntu16.0.4 so I used following commands to get VirtualBox.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2
```

After I installed VirtualBox, typed a command like :

`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1`

But it says : 
**sudo: docker-machine: command not found**

So I typed another command to check if I have installed VirtualBox correctly.

**sudo virtualbox version**

This opens the **Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager**, which means I did install VirtualBox correctly , but not sure.

Could anyone help me with a proper solution? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed docker-machine as per
https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/ ?
In the prerequisites it states that you must have Docker machine installed and that on Linux it does not come pre-installed

Comment: No,I haven't. Let me try to install docker-machine as per docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to install `Docker Machine` first on your local machine. If you use `Ubuntu`, just use this snippet (Update the version from the [Official Repository Releases](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases) if needed) :

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine &&
chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine &&
sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Comment: I used this inside my virtualbox, but it didn't work. The binary gets created with "Not Found" string inside it.

Comment: This answers installs an outdated version of Docker Machine. [I've added an answer with links to up to date instructions and the releases page on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50770461/8015265).

Answer (score 33):

**The accepted answer contains outdated install instructions!**

Up to date instructions for Docker Machine can be found in [the official documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/#install-machine-directly). This includes instructions for MacOS, Linux (including Ubuntu) & Windows with Git BASH. [Full documentation can be found here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/).

While @sdey0081's answer is more or less correct, running the posted commands will result in an outdated version of Docker Machine being installed. The version it installs is `v0.13.0` while the current release at the time of writing is `v0.15.0`. You can find the available releases in the [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases).

Comment: This one is the real answer referring to the official documentation is just right.

Comment: This is the correct answer, for sure. Still I have to say that I'm a bit troubled by how comfortable people are expected to be with downloading and running binaries on Linux systems, these days.

Comment: The big difference is that according to docs, you have to install docker on your machine. That will increase overhead significantly just to use docker-machine.

Answer (score 5):

On MacOS installing with *brew* is the simplest solution: `brew install docker-machine`

Answer (score 1):

Just additional information with steps to the main answer:

1) To [install docker-machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases) you need to write this as mantioned [@coturiv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533180/8370915):

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.1/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine &&
    chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine &&
    sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

2) If you get the error after running the command `docker-machine create`:

```
Error creating machine: Error with pre-create check: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
```

[be sure](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2608#issuecomment-242892129) that you also installed `virtualbox`:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

3) If you get again [the error](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4271#issuecomment-385313401) like:

```
This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
```

try to run the command `docker-machine create` using `--virtualbox-no-vtx-check` like:

```
docker-machine create default --virtualbox-no-vtx-check
```

Comment: this answer suffers the same issue of recommending an outdated version

Comment: @DaveLak that's why I wrote as additional information to the main answer. It can be helpful if you reproduce these issues and want to understand/analyze why it happens to you while trying to solve the main problem, but also you can improve it if you know how.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/machine/ :

Docker Machine has been deprecated. Please use Docker Desktop instead. See Docker Desktop for Mac and Docker Desktop for Windows. You can also use other cloud provisioning tools.

Comment: What about linux?

Comment: EDIT - docker desktop seems to also support linux